# Database Diagram as file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, documentation

I use `SQL Server 2008 R2` and want to document my database. what's the best software for create diagram from database and have viewer for view created diagram on other system.

EDIT1:

I want this tools have below facility :

- Create Colored diagram
- show/hide one-one, one-many relation
- show/hide relation description
- show/hide indexes of each table
- additional description
- columns Type, size, description , ...
- can grouping tables in diagram
- can save as file.
- have viewer for show created diagram in other system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use database diagrams (from SSMS) then copy it to clipboard and then.. paste in Word, Paint or somewhere..

Comment: I want to create beautiful diagram with additional information, and `SSMS` not a good tools for my purpose.

Comment: @mehdilotfi then you could describe you requirements in question. "Not good tool", "beautiful", "additional information" are terms that does not say much about your needs..